# QGIS Attribute Visibility Issue - Only 6 Attributes Visible on Map

Tags: qgis

I'm facing an attribute visibility issue in QGIS, and I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot it. Here are the details:

I have a layer in my QGIS project with a total of 99 attributes in the attribute table.
However, when I add this layer to my map, I can only see 6 attributes displayed on the map's attribute table.
I've checked the Layer Properties, and all 99 attributes are selected to be displayed.
There are no active filters or symbology settings that should hide any attributes.
I even tried opening the same layer in a new project, but the issue persists.
I suspect it might be related to the way I duplicated the layers or a potential project corruption issue, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Could anyone please provide guidance on how to diagnose and resolve this issue? Has anyone encountered a similar problem before?

Comment: I think you mean features when you say attributes? Try [fix geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisfixgeometries)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: The firsts things to check are superposition and null geometry

Comment: Some screenshots of what you are seeing would be useful to add to the question.